# Disable transparent huge pages in TokuMX

Tags: tokumx

When I try to start the mongod server by giving ./mongod --dbpath /nlu/ind/mongodata
I get an error saying

`TokuMX will not run with transparent huge pages enabled.
    Tue Aug 20 10:47:34 [initandlisten]  Please disable them to continue.
    Tue Aug 20 10:47:34 [initandlisten]  (echo never >       /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled)
     Tue Aug 20 10:47:34 [initandlisten]
     Tue Aug 20 10:47:34 [initandlisten]  The assertion failure you are about to see is    intentional`

Please let me know how to sort this.  Thanks in advance for your help.
I have 3 directories in `/sys/kernel/mm/` and they are `hugepages  ksm redhat_transparent_hugepage`

Comment: This question is about TokuMX, not MongoDB.

Comment: TokuMX is a database engine for MongoDB.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TokuMX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message states, you need to do the following:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled'
```

You can `cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` to see the current setting and to make sure that your echo worked.

The setting will be cleared when you reboot when setting it in this manner. TokuMX sets this in it's init script.

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this question for a more thorough discussion: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99154/disable-transparent-hugepages

You can add `transparent_hugepage=never` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` option in `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub`

To test that it took effect`cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled` should look like this: `always madvise [never]`